# Why declare variable with json in js file instead of reading json?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson, leaflet.markercluster

Recently I've been working with `leaflets`, and I'm currently looking at several plugins.

Several of the plugins I've seen (including [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)) use `json` to plot points, but instead of using the actual stream, or a `json` file, the programmer includes a javascript `.js` file where a variable is set with the json stream. So the `js` file with the json data looks like this:

```
var data = [
    {"loc":[41.575330,13.102411], "title":"aquamarine"},
    {"loc":[41.575730,13.002411], "title":"black"},
    {"loc":[41.807149,13.162994], "title":"blue"},
    {"loc":[41.507149,13.172994], "title":"chocolate"}
]
```

I've been working with other type of javascript charts, and most of them read and process a json stream.

It seems these plugins will not work if I create a service that returns json.

Why not use json instead of including a js file that sets a variable with a json stream?

I'm not a javascript expert, but I find it easier to generate json than a javascript file with json in it.

Comment: It's probably to avoid CORS issues. JS files are easy to load across domains.

Comment: Would the example run into CORS issues if the json file is in the same folder as the example that's reading it?

Comment: No, that's not across different domains. Without seeing how the plugin is coded, it's hard to guess why they did this.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong about concepts.

1st. JavaScript as a language has its own syntax, so, if you have a function that receive a JSON object as a parameter and you pass it a Number or a String, it'll will throw an Error when you try to access some property. For Ex.

```
function myjson (obj) {
    console.log(obj.prop)
}

myjson(34); //wrong
myjson("{prop: 123}") //wrong
myjson({prop: 123}) //Good, will print 123
```

Now, imagine that you have some scripts, many .js files that you have indexed in your HTML file, like

```
<script src="/mycode.js"> </script>
<script src="/myapp.js"> </script>
```

And you want to add some data, like the one you show for the plot points; then you have to include it in two ways, putting that in a .js file or getting it from a service with an AJAX call.

If you add that in a .js file, you'll have access to them directly from your code, like this

```js
var data = [
    {"loc":[41.575330,13.102411], "title":"aquamarine"},
    {"loc":[41.575730,13.002411], "title":"black"},
    {"loc":[41.807149,13.162994], "title":"blue"},
    {"loc":[41.507149,13.172994], "title":"chocolate"}
]

console.log(data)
```

and if you put that in a .json file file this

> /mydata.json

```
[
    {"loc":[41.575330,13.102411], "title":"aquamarine"},
    {"loc":[41.575730,13.002411], "title":"black"},
    {"loc":[41.807149,13.162994], "title":"blue"},
    {"loc":[41.507149,13.172994], "title":"chocolate"}
]
```

you'll have to fetch and parse the data yourself

```
fetch("/mydata.json").then(async data => {
    var myjson = await data.text();
    myjson = JSON.parse(myjson);
    console.log(myjson) //A Javascript object
    console.log(myjson[1]) //The first element
})
```

Comment: I guess my point is that the purpose of `json` is to transmit data between a server and web application. So why complicate that by saving it into a javascript file?

Comment: I understand that json is a language and javascript is a data-interchange format.

Comment: What I'm saying is that most of these leaflets plugins will use data from another server, so why not just use raw json? Why create a javascript file with the json data and include that file in the HTML?

Comment: Not a very good example to use fetch API here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf "_json is a language and javascript is a data-interchange format_" => that is the other way around

Comment: @Kaiido fetch API doens't work if your response is an array, JSON.parse API do.

Comment: Where did you saw that? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json#Returns

Comment: I've used a lot the Fetch API and if want to parse an array [1,2,3,4,5] you have to put it inside an object {"foo": [1,2,3,4,5]}, other way will throw an Error

Answer (score 1):

I like [@FernandoCarvajal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52563688/5108796), but I would add more context to it:

1. JSON is more recent than JS (you could see JSON as a "spin-off" of JS, even though it is now used in combination with much more languages than just JS).
2. Before JSON was widespread, the main and easiest way to load external data in Browsers was the technique you saw in the plugins demo: assign data into a global variable, which you can use in the next script. Browsers happily execute JS even from cross domain (unless you explicitly specify a Content Security Policy). The only drawback is that you have to agree on a global variable name beforehand. But for static sites (like GitHub pages in the case of the plugins demo you mention), it is easy for the developer(s) to agree on such a convention.

At this stage, you should understand that using this simple technique already fits the job for the sake of the plugins static demo. It also avoids browsers compatibility issues, aligning with Leaflet wide browsers compatibility.

3. With the advent of richer clients / Front-End, typically with AJAX, we can get rid of the global variable name agreement issue, but now we may face cross domain difficulty, as pointed out by [@Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52563506/why-declare-variable-with-json-in-js-file-instead-of-reading-json#comment92065506_52563506). We also start hitting browsers compatibility hell.
4. Now that we can load arbitrary data without having to agree on a static name beforehand, we can leverage Back-End served dynamic content to a bigger scale.
5. To workaround the cross domain issue, and before CORS was widespread, we started using JSONP: the Front-End specifies the agreed (callback) name in its request. But in fact we just fallback to a similar technique as in point 2, mainly adding asynchronicity.
6. Now that we have CORS, we can more simply use AJAX / fetch techniques, and avoid security issues inherent to JSONP. We also replace the old school XML by the more JS-like JSON.

There is nothing preventing you from replacing the old school technique in point 2 by a more modern JSON consumption. If you want to ensure wide browsers compatibility, make sure to use libraries that take care of it (like jQuery, etc.). And if you need cross domain, make sure to enable CORS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that 90% of all the examples, even the more recent ones, include a javascript file in the html.

Comment: Using a `js` file defeats the purpose of the chart consuming external data so it's dynamic. It's like me opening the html and typing in the values to be plotted.

Comment: I guess the majority use leaflets to display a static set of points.

Comment: What I hear in your comments is that you are looking for an example or tutorial of how to retrieve plain JSON data and then use it in Leaflet. But what you currently find is demos where the data is hard coded. And you do not know how to make the step to replace the hard coded data by dynamically retrieved data. That should be quite a trivial task for a JS developer, and [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52580346/5108796) of your new question looks well good enough.

Comment: That's pretty much it. What I don't seem to understand is why almost all the examples have hard-coded data when the purpose of leaflets is to read dynamic data.

Comment: "_the purpose of leaflets is to read dynamic data_": what makes you think so, especially when you previously drew your own conclusion that "_the majority use leaflets to display a static set of points_"?

Comment: You seem to have a strong grasp on the subject, and I appreciate your help. Do you think leaflets is primarily used to read hard-coded data or was it meant to read dynamic data coming from an external service?

Comment: My personal opinion is that Leaflet was meant to display… geographical data. Now the first usage you might think about would be to display some particular places, which probably do not move. But it is also easy to display dynamic data (i.e. objects which change places from time to time), or even real-time (i.e. objects which move continuously, like cars). See for example [Leaflet Realtime](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) and [PruneCluster](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/PruneCluster) plugins.