# Convert javascript to json?

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I'm working with leaflets and I've noticed that many examples use a separate `js` file where a variable is set to a `JSON` stream.

How would I be able to modify the following example so that it can read off a `json` file with the `geojson` and not have the variable declaration in the javascript?

The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var geoJsonData = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection", 
        "features": [
            { "type": "Feature", "id":"1", "properties": { "address": "2"   }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2209316333,-37.8210922667 ] } },
            { "type": "Feature", "id":"2", "properties": { "address": "151" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2238417833,-37.80975435   ] } },
            { "type": "Feature", "id":"3", "properties": { "address": "21"  }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2169955667,-37.818193     ] } },
            { "type": "Feature", "id":"4", "properties": { "address": "14"  }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2240856667,-37.8216963    ] } },
            { "type": "Feature", "id":"5", "properties": { "address": "38B" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2196982333,-37.8188702167 ] } },
            { "type": "Feature", "id":"6", "properties": { "address": "38"  }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [175.2209942   ,-37.8192782833 ] } }
        ]
    };

    var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });

    var map = L.map('map')
            .addLayer(tiles);

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.address);
        }
    });
    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

    map.addLayer(markers);
    map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
</script>
```

I know it can be done with `$.getJSON`, but I would prefer using `L.geoJson`, if possible.

Comment: Hi @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf, I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for a way to send JSON data through a stream? or are you looking for a way to fetch JSON data from a remote file?

Comment: Hi, I already have `points.json` with the geojson data. I would like to modify the example so that it reads from this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read JSON data from a file you can use the `fetch` function ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)).

Here is an example:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        // Do something with the JSON data
        console.table(myJson);
    });
```

In your case:

```
function doSomething(geoJsonData) {
    var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });

    var map = L.map('map')
            .addLayer(tiles);

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonData, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.address);
        }
    });
    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

    map.addLayer(markers);
    map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
}

fetch('http://myserver.com/myfile.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(doSomething)
    .catch(function(err) {
        // In case of error, display the error message
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Notice that I put your code inside a callback function, as the `fetch` function is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Being new to leaflets, would the code change drastically if I were to read the geojson with something like this? `$.getJSON("Points.json",function(data){
    L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
});`

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf unfortunatly, that a leaftlet-specific question and I don't know the answer. Please look at ghybs's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the geoJSON variable in a separate .js file and import it into the main logic .js file. Try pasting your var geoJsonData in a file called geoJsonData.js, then at the bottom of that file add "module.exports = geoJsonData;". Then on your logic file (ie scripts.js), you can import the variable as is by adding "var geoJsonData = require("./geoJsonData.js"); at the top. Then your call to add the points to the map would be

```
function geoJsonMarkers() {  
$.getJSON(geoJsonData, function (data) {
        // this adds the GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
        L.geoJson(data).addTo(mymap);
}
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confused between backend / build import and frontend asynchronous fetch (jQuery getJSON).

Answer (score 0):

> I know it can be done with `$.getJSON`, but I would prefer using `L.geoJson`, if possible.

You seem to not realize that these 2 functions provide different steps of your workflow, as illustrated by the 2 other answers.

You may be misled by other libraries that provide utility functions which perform both steps for you.

jQuery's `$.getJSON` is to fetch / retrieve data from your server.

Once you have the resulting JS object, you feed it into Leaflet's `L.geoJSON` factory to have it converted into Leaflet layers.